# How to initialize wchar_t pointer correctly in constructor and delete it in destructor

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to initialize a `wchar_t*` in my class.

This is my constructor:

```
Book::Book()
{
    book = 0;
    auth = 0;
    setBook(TEXT(""));
    setAuth(TEXT(""));
}
```

And this is my destructor:

```
Book::~Book()
{
    if (book)
        delete book;
    if (auth)
        delete auth;
}
```

and here is `setBook()`:

```
void Book::setBook(TCHAR *a) {
    if (book)
        delete book;
    book = new TCHAR[lstrlen(a) + 1];
    lstrcpy(book, a);
}
```

The problem is that when i'm trying to create new object and push it to vector, I get a run time error "The program has triggered a breakpoint" when delete book in destructor.

Here is my vector:

```
for (int i = 0; !feof(f); i++) {
        reqBook.push_back(Book());
        reqBook[i].read(f);
    }
```

Please any idea about my problem, or how to initialize correctly?.

Comment: You should use delete[].

Comment: Don't.  Use a `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: My tip is that you *don't*. Use [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead. It's a template class, and you can use it with `TCHAR`.

Comment: As a side node, the check here is unnecessary: `if (book) delete book;`. You can just write `delete book;`

Comment: With such an incomplete example, it's hard to know.  For a start, you mention `wchar_t*`, but then you haven't written any in the code you've shown us.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on using library types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manage resources, you *must* have a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator (or delete them).  This is The Rule of 3.  With C++11, it's a good idea to have a move constructor and a move assignment operator too (the rule of 5).

If you try to make `Book` the class that manages resources, you will find there are some complexities involved with exception safety when you are part-way through copying or constructing `book` or `auth`.

The solution is to write a RAII class which encapsulates handling an array of `wchar_t`, and make both `book` and `auth` be objects of that class.  When you have done that, you will find that you have made a poor-man's copy of `std::wstring`.

The *only* reason not to use `std::wstring` for this, is if it is a class assignment where you have been specifically forbidden from using it.

The specific reason for your crash, is that `std::vector` copies your original `Book` object.  When it does so, it uses the compiler generated copy constructor (because you haven't provided one).  This just copies the pointers.  The destructor of the original object deletes the memory these pointers are pointing at, and now you are in the world of pain known as "undefined behaviour".  When the object in the vector is deleted, it too will try to delete the same memory, and anything can happen - hitting a breakpoint is a particularly painless result.